# Como escapar caracteres no Batch do Windows?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
start "" "https://site.com.br/app/index.jsf?username=nomecabuloso&token=tokenzera"
```

Porém, quando eu executo, ele não passa do `index.jsf`, ele abre o seguinte url:

```
https://site.com.br/app/index.jsf
```

Já tentei utilizar a tecla de escape `\`, para o `?`, mas não funciona.

Minha dúvida é, como fazer ele executar o link inteiro?

Comment: Era pras aspas já escaparem os caracteres.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para escpar caracteres use o acento circunflexo `^`

Comment: @Francisco o `&` é um caracter especial então precisa de um `^` nele também.

Comment: Percebi. Consegui fazer funcionar, vlw.

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa de nada disso,basta fazer assim:

```
@echo off
start chrome "https://site.com.br/app/index.jsf?username=nomecabuloso&token=tokenzera"
```

**Obs**: troque o nome do navegador pelo navegador que você irá abrir.

Answer (score 0):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Para usar passando **`argumento/parâmetro`** e não necessitando de prévias edições nos caracteres **`especiais`** presentes no **`link`**.

---

Basicamente, o **`bat`** vai jogar o argumento/parâmetro (**`%1`**) no loop **`for`** e já adicionado aspas (**`usebackq`**)

---

> **`Q236618.cmd "%1"`**

---

```
Q236618.cmd "https://site.com.br/app/index.jsf?username=nomecabuloso&token=tokenzera"
```

---

> **`Código Q236618.cmd`** com argumento **`'%1'`** no **`for`** usando **`usebackq`**...

---

```
@echo off & for /f usebackq %%i in ('%1')do start "" /b %%i
```

---

> **`Código Q236618.cmd`** com **`'%1'`** ou **`'link'`** direto no **`for`** usando **`usebackq`** filtrado num **`if`**...

---

```
@echo off 
if not ".%~1" == "." (for /f usebackq %%i in ('%1')do start "" /b %%i) else (
for /f usebackq %%i in ('"https://site.com.br/app/index.jsf?username=nomecabuloso&token=tokenzera"')do start "" /b %%i)
```